# How to get detailed installation log while the update package is being installed remotely using SPE?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I'm using SPE to install the TDS `.update` package file.

How do I get detailed installation log remotely in the script below?

**Current PowerShell Script:**

```
$SitecoreInstanceUri = "https://helixsite.local"
$Username = "admin"
$Password = "b"
$SitecorePackagePath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\helixsite.local\App_Data\packages\Helix.Project.Website.Master.update"

#Create a new script session
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username $Username -Password $Password -ConnectionUri $SitecoreInstanceUri

Write-Host "Installing Sitecore update package '$SitecorePackagePath' on '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"

$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $package = $using:SitecorePackagePath
    Write-Log "Installing Sitecore update package '$package'"
    Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install
} -AsJob -Verbose

if (!$jobId) { 
    Write-Host "No jobId was created. Please check if your Powershell Remoting is activated on the target instance '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"
}

#doneScript is the script that gets executed every 5 seconds and checks the state of the executed script. It returns a custom PowerShell object with Name, IsDone and Status
$doneScript = {
        $backgroundScriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $using:jobId
        $isDone = $backgroundScriptSession -eq $null -or $backgroundScriptSession.State -ne "Busy"
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Name" = $backgroundScriptSession.Id
            "IsDone" = $isDone
            "Status" = "$($backgroundScriptSession.State)"
        }
    }

try {
    $keepRunning = $true
    while($keepRunning) {
        #Execute the doneScript and check the response.
        $response = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock $doneScript
        if($response -and $response.IsDone) {
            $keepRunning = $false
            Write-Host "Polling job $($response.Name). Status : $($response.Status)."
            Write-Host "Finished polling job $($id)."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Polling job $($response.Name). Status : $($response.Status)."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }
    }   
} catch {
    if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "ScriptSessionNotFound,Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.ScriptSessions.GetScriptSessionCommand") {
        Write-Host "Package installation triggered application pool recycling."
    }
    else
    {
     throw
    }
}


Write-Host "Sitecore update package installed."
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

**Current output is as below:**

```
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
... This keeps running for few minutes ...
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Busy.
Polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6. Status : Available.
Finished polling job d8400253-9f9e-4718-89d5-0dd633bf3bf6.
Sitecore update package installed.
```

**Expected output:**

I'm assuming remotely somehow we should be able to get installation logs as below.

```
Installing item '/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Submit Actions/Send E-mail'  
Installing item '/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Submit Actions/Submit Action'
```

I was reading about the output type from `Install-UpdatePackage` command is `List<ContingencyEntry>` but I'm not sure how to read it remotely and display that in the output locally.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried below variation in the script above but it doesn't change anything in output in the console.

```
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $package = $using:SitecorePackagePath
    Write-Log "Installing Sitecore update package '$package'"
    Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.ShortDescription; }
} -AsJob -Verbose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the PowerShell script working as follows:

**Script:**

```
$SitecoreInstanceUri = "https://helixsite.local"
$Username = "admin"
$Password = "b"
$SitecorePackagePath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\helixsite.local\App_Data\packages\Helix.Project.Website.Master.update"

#Create a new script session
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username $Username -Password $Password -ConnectionUri $SitecoreInstanceUri

Write-Host "Installing Sitecore update package '$SitecorePackagePath' on '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"

$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $package = $using:SitecorePackagePath
    Write-Log "Installing Sitecore update package '$package'"
    Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install | Format-Table ShortDescription -Verbose
} -AsJob -Verbose

if (!$jobId) { 
    Write-Host "No jobId was created. Please check if your Powershell Remoting is activated on the target instance '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"
}

#doneScript is the script that gets executed every 5 seconds and checks the state of the executed script. It returns a custom PowerShell object with Name, IsDone and Status
$doneScript = {
        $backgroundScriptSession = Get-ScriptSession -Id $using:jobId
        $isDone = $backgroundScriptSession -eq $null -or $backgroundScriptSession.State -ne "Busy"
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Name" = $backgroundScriptSession.Id
            "IsDone" = $isDone
            "Status" = "$($backgroundScriptSession.State)"
        }
    }

try {
    $keepRunning = $true
    while($keepRunning) {
        #Execute the doneScript and check the response.
        $response = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock $doneScript
        if($response -and $response.IsDone) {
            $keepRunning = $false
            Write-Host "Polling job $($response.Name). Status : $($response.Status)."
            Write-Host "Finished polling job $($id)."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Polling job $($response.Name). Status : $($response.Status)."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }
    }   
} catch {
    if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "ScriptSessionNotFound,Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.ScriptSessions.GetScriptSessionCommand") {
        Write-Host "Package installation triggered application pool recycling."
    }
    else
    {
     throw
    }
}

Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $ss = Get-ScriptSession -Id $using:JobId
    $ss | Receive-ScriptSession
}

Write-Host "Sitecore update package installed."
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

**What changed here**

Changed from this,

```
Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install
```

To this script,

```
Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install | Format-Table ShortDescription -Verbose
```

If there are a lot of updates included in the update package then the response can get pretty huge and it can cause `request timeout` or `connection timeout`.

So to avoid it timeout issues, I'm reading just one property `ShortDescription` in the response from `List<ContingencyEntry>` which is returned from [`Install-UpdatePackage`](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/install-updatepackage#outputs). We can cut down on the response by using filter `Where-Object` in the script above if needed. Also, it is required to add `-Verbose` to this part of script to receive the response remotely.

Secondly to get the response in the local console OR to the CI/CD output I have added this section in the end right before closing the session,

```
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $ss = Get-ScriptSession -Id $using:JobId
    $ss | Receive-ScriptSession
}
```

I hope this helps.